# Is it possible to convert pdf to text?

Tags: android, pdf

In my application I am downloading pdf file from the net. Is it possible in Android to convert that pdf file into text (String or character)?

Comment: This is a q&a site supported by volunteers, please don't use phrases like "this is very urgent", as they can have the reverse effect. If you want quick response, make sure you ask your question as clearly as possible.

Comment: Actually, how is this related to programming? Perhaps better suited on http://superuser.com?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it is possible to convert PDF to text. A better term than convert would be extract though.

You only need an OCR tool if the PDF has images only. This is typically the case if the PDF is a result of scanning documents. But even then, text is often inserted by the scan driver as invisible text so that the PDF content can be searched.

Answer (score -4):

Bruno Lowagie (Developer of iText) says unfortunately no.

> That's very normal. It's 'in the nature' of PDF.
>   PDF is a one-way process. The PDF is the end product.
>   You are not supposed to convert it to text.
>
> You need an OCR tool.

http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Convert-PDF-to-text-td2142916.html

Regards Stefan