# How can I display a pdf document into a TextView?

Tags: android, pdf-reader, pdftotext

I want to read pdf files and display contents on `TextView`. is it possible ? or just show pdf into `WebView` or pdfViewer?

i want to do like it,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView showText;
String url="http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    showText= (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.showtext);
    showText.setText( ++ convertPdfTotext ++);


}


public void convertPdfTotext(View view)
{

}

}
```

Comment: If you extract text from a pdf, it's gonna be a mess. A bloody mess, in fact. Use a pdf viewer of some kind. Even if you were to extract the text in the correct order and such, you'll lose any markup.

Comment: u can open the pdf file on webview nat able to view pdf file on text view if u want thna read pdf file than set text on text view

Comment: look at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7201054/1847645

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use it in text view you can convert it with itext as string,but you'll loose formatting:

```
    PdfTextExtractor parser =new PdfTextExtractor(new PdfReader("C:/Text.pdf"));
parser.getTextFromPage(3);
```

Use WebView instead and you can enable even zoom.

```
WebView mWebView=new WebView(MyPdfViewActivity.this);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+LinkTo);
```