# How I read file PDF in SD card in Android?

Tags: android, pdf, sd-card

I have a .PDF file saved on my sdcard. I need to read the content of .PDF file and show it in a TextView.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this for example - get the file path and open it as a new intent:

```
// get the file path from the external storage (SD card)
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/yourPdfName.pdf");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
// set the content type and data of the intent
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
// start the intent as a new activity
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: That will not show the content of the pdf file in a TxtView.

Comment: take a look at this question for displaying it in a textView http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739313/how-can-i-display-a-pdf-document-into-a-textview