# Read text from google drive pdf and doc files android

Tags: android, pdf, google-drive-api

**When I try to read text from drive files like pdf and doc, the text format is coming as the following way.**

````
%PDF-1.3
%âãÏÓ
7 0 obj
<</Linearized 1/L 7945/O 9/E 3524/N 1/T 7656/H [ 451 137]>>
endobj
13 0 obj
<</DecodeParms<</Columns 4/Predictor 12>>/Filter/FlateDecode/ID[<4DC91A1875A6D707AEC203BB021C93A0><F6C92B368A8A13408457A1D395A37EB9>]/Index[7 21]/Info 6 0 R/Length 52/Prev 7657/Root 8 0 R/Size 28/Type/XRef/W[1 2 1]>>stream
hÞbbd``b`² ±H0§ 6G ñå#Ã4,#¹ÄÆ_L¤ð
endstream
endobj
startxref
0
%%EOF
27 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/I 69/Length 58/S 38>>stream
hÞb```a``üÏÜ6¨¬$ËÑ¬,ÆÅ
ÜÜÓt&¬8ÌZ-R,¿â
endstream
endobj
8 0 obj
<</Metadata 1 0 R/Pages 5 0 R/Type/Catalog>>
endobj
9 0 obj
<</Contents 11 0 R/CropBox[0 0 595 842]/MediaBox[0 0 595 842]/Parent 5 0 R/Resources 14 0 R/Rotate 0/Type/Page>>
endobj
````

**Please find the code below:**

```
DriveContents contents = result.getDriveContents();  
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(contents.getInputStream()));    
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();  
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {  
    builder.append(line);  
}  
String contentsAsString = builder.toString();
```

But actually, i need text in original format as [here](http://che.org.il/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pdf-sample.pdf)

Please help me out in this.

Comment: PDF files are not plain text files, and your code will only work for plain text files. Find a PDF library (e.g., iText) that understands the PDF file format.

Answer (score 0):

In additon to what Commonsware has said, if you simply want to view the pdf file, you can use webViewLink of the file through [Files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get). But if you really want to convert the pdf file and "extract" the text, you're going to need some kind of Android OCR conversion library like the ones mentioned in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201054/is-it-possible-to-convert-pdf-to-text) such as the [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract).