# how to pick and select a .pdf file from internal and external storage in android device and show the file in text view

Tags: android, pdf

i use below  code for select pdf file but it not shows the pdf file.

following is request code.

```
 if (requestCode == 3) {
     String FilePath = data.getData().getPath();
     String FileName = data.getData().getLastPathSegment();
     int lastPos = FilePath.length() - FileName.length();
     String Folder = FilePath.substring(0, lastPos);

     // textFile.setText("Full Path: \n" + FilePath + "\n");
     //textFolder.setText("Folder: \n" + Folder + "\n");
     //textFileName.setText("File Name: \n" + FileName + "\n");
 }
```

on button click.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
  intent.setType("application/pdf");
  startActivityForResult(intent,3);
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39696906/select-pdf-file-from-phone-on-button-click-and-display-its-file-name-on-textview

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201054/is-it-possible-to-convert-pdf-to-text

Comment: i used this code but it is not showing any pdf file @kapsym

Comment: Are you looking for a a particular location? Is your PDF file available in that location

Comment: no i want to pick from external and internal storage @kapsym